# Multiple index keywords in a row

Tags: macros, indexing

Is there a way to declare multiple `\index{}`keywords with a single command, instead of declaring them separately?

More precisely, instead of doing `\index{keyword1}, \index{keyword2}, \index{keyword3}, \index{keyword4}`, I would like to do something like `\multipleIndex{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4}`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try the following example if it fits your needs. I use `\foreach` statement from the `pgffor`/`tikz`/`pgfplots` package.

```
%! *latex mal-index.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\def\multipleIndex#1{\foreach\entry in{#1}{\index{\entry}}}
\begin{document}
My first paragraph.
\index{test1}%
\index{test2}%
\multipleIndex{a,b,c,d}
\end{document}
```

The generated `mal-index.idx` file looks like this:

```
\indexentry{test1}{1}
\indexentry{test2}{1}
\indexentry{a}{1}
\indexentry{b}{1}
\indexentry{c}{1}
\indexentry{d}{1}
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the name `\index`, i.e. defining `\let\oldindex\index` and so forth or would this clutter the internal implementation of `\index`?

Comment: @barto I'm not redefining the `\index` command, so you can apply your idea for your needs.

Answer (score 5):

With `xparse` it's almost a one liner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeindex

\NewDocumentCommand{\mindex}{ >{\SplitList{,}} m }
 {%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\index}%
 }

\begin{document}
x\mindex{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword1!keyword4}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Of course `imakeidx` is just for convenience; also `makeidx` would do.

[image]

If you want to keep `\index` (although I don't recommend it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeindex

\let\originalindex\index
\RenewDocumentCommand{\index}{ >{\SplitList{,}} m }
  {%
   \ProcessList{#1}{\originalindex}%
  }

\begin{document}
x\index{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword1!keyword4}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the name `\index`, i.e. defining `\let\oldindex\index` and so forth or would this clutter the internal implementation of `\index`?

Comment: @barto Yes, it is; I'll add it.

Comment: Ah yes, I see why it is not recommended since one may have keywords containing commas. In that case it appears possible to work around it by putting the commas between curly braces, like `{,}`.

Comment: @barto Overloading a command should be done with care.